# beforeunload - own message and function success and false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

The following code always show the same message: **This page is asking you to confirm** etc. Is it possible to change this text to show something else?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

});
```

Is it possible to query whether the user actually leaves the page or if she stays?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    if(return == 'stay on page'){
        alert('stay');
    }
    if(return == 'leave page'){
        alert('stay');
    }
});
```

Is this possible?

And is possible detect close windows without alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the default dialogue for onbeforeunload, so something like ...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'You have unsaved changes!';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'You have unsaved changes!';
};
```

Comment: on my Firefox i have still This page is asking you to confirm etc. Is possible disable all alert ?